# DNS e-mail - how to catch all @mydomain.com e-mails and sent to one specific e-mail account?

Tags: email, dns, cname

Im currently control my MX records at a DNS service provider.
Lets say my e-mail is: `info@mydomain.com`

**How would I go about configuring my DNS so that it would do a catch all** - on all @mydomain.com emails and sent them to `info@mydomain.com` (which is my main working e-mail adress) ?
So if an email is sent to `hello@mydomain.com` it would automatically end up at `info@mydomain.com`

My MX records like this:

```
mydomain.com    aspmx.l.google.com  1   43200   

mydomain.com    aspmx3.googlemail.com   10  43200   

mydomain.com    aspmx2.googlemail.com   10  43200   

mydomain.com    alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 5   43200   

mydomain.com    alt2.aspmx.l.google.com 5   43200
```

EDIT:
Not sure if this is relevant, but just some additional information:

- The main email account `info@mydomain.com` is setup with google app mail
  service
- I receive all my emails via Thunderbird (POP3?)

Comment: This is rather set up on a mail server basis rather than relying on DNS. Which MTA are you using?

Comment: Hi napcae, thanks for your response. Im not totally sure what an MTA is - however see my edit and let me know if that would make anything more clear in regards of this

Comment: DNS doesn't handle your email addresses, your mail server does.  DNS tells people where to find your mail server on the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Google App Mail Service then the answer is kind of straight forward.  Google itself is providing a help document for a catch all address, which can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962).

It basically requires you to

1. sign in to the Google Admin Console
2. either go to Settings > Gmail or Google Apps > Gmail > User Settings
3. Set Up the Catch All Address

I hope this is helping you.

Comment: It was as simple as what you suggested. Thanks so much for guiding me the right way!